# open multiple text files and read until specific character

Tags: python, pandas, loops, text

I would like to read several text files but they are too long so i want to stop reading them at the first `'}'`.

EDIT: The code below works without error but it fails to cut the text file when it encounters `'}'` for the first time. I would like to stop reading at the end of the second line of the sample (where there is `'}'`)

EDIT 2: I have added `readline` statement in the code.

SAMPLE:

```
{"offset":"14758816658","bids":[["968899.79379","0.01000000","0.01000000","0","1093577338","29194","5","14758816598","1"],["968899.35295","0.02100000","0.02100000","0","1093577193","29194","5","14758816186","1"],
...["9999999.00000","0.01000000","0.01000000","0","568775590","75620","5","12301971393","1"]]}
{"offset":"14758825743","bids":[["968019.05000","0.09815250","0.09815250","0","1093580802","243454","5","14758825261","1"],["968019.00000","0.18740000","0.18740000","0","1093580826","221763","5","14758825331","1"],
```

THE CODE:

```
        with open(fileName, 'r') as fileName:
            line = fileName.readline()
                for x in line:
                    if x == '}':
                        break
            data = pd.read_csv(fileName, lineterminator= str(']'), low_memory= False, error_bad_lines=False, header= None)
            print(data)
```

EDIT: I run the code as below. Correct output for the `print` but still the entire set of data when I `pd.read.csv`

```
with open(fileName, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fileName:
      print(re.findall(r'(\{[^\{\}]*})', fileName.readline())[0])
      data = pd.read_csv(fileName, lineterminator= str(']'), low_memory= False, error_bad_lines=False, header= None)
```

EDIT 2: THE SOLUTION

```
 with open(fileName, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fileName:
            d = io.StringIO(re.findall(r'(\{[^\{\}]*})', fileName.readline())[0])
            data = pd.read_csv(d, lineterminator= str(']'), low_memory= False, error_bad_lines=False, header= None)
```

Comment: can you post a sample of what data looks like in your txt file?

Comment: @JialinZou Done

Comment: it looks like your file is structured in JSON-like format. You sure there's no comma in between "}" and "{"?

Comment: Ok, yes i am sure. I have copy past this part as is.

Comment: If not stop reading in the text source, is there a way to make the pd.read_csv to stop reading when it first meet the `'}'`

Comment: The way you have it written, it *starts* reading it there, as near as I can tell. You iterate, character by character, until you find the `')'`. Then you start reading. (Also, if it's a line-oriented file, why not `readline` or `readlines`?)

Comment: @MIke I have added the `readline` in the code which separate the data properly but this code is part of a loop and the loop goes to infinity after the modification. Is this related to `break`? Basically the code open text files and read them one after the other until the `}`

Comment: There's an old school algorithmic design technique that, while tedious, really helps newer programmers improve. It's called "desk checking." You sit down with a paper and pencil and, for each statement and for each iteration of a loop, you write down what the variables contain and what is shown on the screen. Googling "desk checking programming" should get you on your way. I'm pretty confident you can figure this problem out. :)

Comment: @Mike thanks for your advise. I manage to solve it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex match and get the value. Below snippet will give you first `{.*}` from file.

```
import re
with open('string.txt') as s:
    print(re.findall(r'(\{[^\{\}]*})', s.read())[0])
```

Comment: thank you very much. It works perfectly for the regex but not when i try to print the `data =` Do you have an idea please? please look at my edit for the code

Comment: You only need first chunk right. Do no print it rather use the below. 

`data = pd.read_json('[{}]'.format(re.findall(r'(\{[^\{\}]*})', s.read())[0]))`

Or if you want to print as well , then store it into a variable and use that variable while creating dataframe. You are getting blank because you file is not in proper csv format so it is dropping all the lines as you are using `error_bad_lines=False`. Either convert if to proper json format and then read JSON or create dataframe using the regex chunks.

Comment: Check below if you want to create dataframe with all the chunks. 
`data = pd.read_json('[{}]'.format(','.join(re.findall(r'(\{[^\{\}]*})', s.read()))))`

Comment: Many thanks, i solved the problem with `io.StringIO`. Still you put me on track. Please look at the EDIT.

Comment: I used read_json directly formatting the string. Both ways are correct. Only matter of understanding :)